# Finding value of slip in an 3-phase delta connected induction motor

Tags: induction-motor, electrical

I know the equation for slip is

```
          s= (Ns-Nr/ns)x100
```

and that to find Ns is

```
         Ns= f/p.
```

I have been given running speed (16.2 rev/s), total number of poles (18), frequency (50Hz).

Can someone help explain how to get a value for Nr?

Comment: Perhaps a bit of internet searching could help. For instance I quickly found [Link](http://culvermotor.com/Engineering-Formulas/Motor-RPM-and-Slip.html). On that page there is a definition for Nr. Which is "nr = rotor rotation speed (rpm)".

Comment: If Nr > Ns, it's not motoring. I suspect one of your parameters is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\$N_R\$ is your rotor rotational speed represented in revolutions per **minute** (rpm). In the question you've been given a rotational speed in revolutions per **second**. Should be a easy as:

$$ N_R \text{ [rpm]} = 16.2 \text{ [rev/s]} * 60 \text{ [s/min]} = 972 \text{ [rpm]} $$

Also, the equation for synchronous rotational speed, \$N_S\$ is:

$$N_S \text{ [rpm]} = \frac{120f \text{ [Hz]}}{p \text{ [poles per phase]}} = \frac{120 * 50}{6} = 1000 \text{ [rpm]} $$

Where \$p\$, your poles per phase, will be eighteen divided by three, for a three-phase motor.